# When applying glScalef() to a polygon, it changes its position, how to get rid of it?

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat

Is a simple polygon.

```
glPushMatrix();
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glVertex3f(-150, 150, 0);
glVertex3f(150, 150, 0);
glVertex3f(150, 450, 0);
glVertex3f(-150, 450, 0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

When applying glScalef() to a polygon, it changes its position, how to get rid of it? I mean... If he was at the same height, he would change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glScalef()` doesn't scale a polygon, it scales an entire coordinate system. Everything will be scaled around the point with coordinates `(0, 0, 0)`, *not* around the center of the polygon.

If you want to scale around some other point `(x, y, z)`, you can use the following code:

```
glTranslatef(x, y, z);
glScalef(your, scale, here);
glTranslatef(-x, -y, -z);
```

Though a more robust solution would be to make your polygon's coordinates relative to its center, in which case you don't need the second glTranslatef() anymore. In your specific example:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, 300, 0);
glScalef(your, scale, here);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
glVertex3f(-150, -150, 0);
glVertex3f(150, -150, 0);
glVertex3f(150, 150, 0);
glVertex3f(-150, 150, 0);
glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```